# Can Anyone help with Scripting for Autohotkey to work with Handbrake?

Tags: scripting, macros, autohotkey

I'm trying to make an autohotkey script so I can drag and drop movie files into autohotkey for it to put it into handbrake's queue to be converted into iphone format.

I just started with autohotkey and have no idea on how to record a macro like that. Can anyone point me the right way or maybe does anyone have a script like that to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handbrake comes with a Command Line program (default path = C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe)

That would probably be your best bet versus trying to make a macro to interact with the GUI version of Handbrake. If you only wanted to do one at a time a simple DOS batch script would allow you to drag and drop files:

1) Open Notepad

2) Paste the following text:

"C:\Program Files\HandBrake\HandBrakeCLI.exe" -i %1 -o %1.mp4 -e x264 -b 2000 -B 128 -X 480

3) Save the file as HandbrakeCLI.bat (or anything else you want as long as it ends in .bat)

4) Place that where the video you want to convert is located and drag the video file onto the .bat file. A DOS window should pop up and start converting the video.

Comment: Thats great! Thanks! But is there a way I can change it to add to queue instead? I have a whole bunch of videos that I'd like to drag and drop. Or if possible drag and drop a directory to it.

Comment: You should check out WinFF. It can convert videos to h.264 also and can do batches of files: 

http://winff.org/